# Cannot access value from Mirth Connect server's globalMap

Tags: javascript, rhino, mirth

My Mirth Connect server contains many fields in its globalMap, and they are visibly present via an up-to-date dashboard view. I ensured it's updated by clicking Refresh as well as re-connecting to the server via Administrator. The problem is that when trying to get these fields from a channel via `globalMap.get(...)`, the function began suddenly unexpectedly returning `null`

This keeps occuring when trying to get other variables - whose values are plainly there upon navigating manually to the globalMap fields - and happens in any channel I invoke from. Interestingly, after appending a new field to globalMap once with `globalMap.put(...)` once, that value is successfully returned upon retrieval

Could I be seeing an out-of-date dashboard view of the global map whose previous data was somehow wiped? Could restarting the server help?

Comment: Please edit [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153908/cannot-get-value-from-globalmap-in-mirth-connect) instead of deleting and re-posting it

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I thought I'd made it more concise - was unsure how to make it more specific without posting sensitive info. Did some rephrasing, but I just see including any code or specific values as noise to the main issue. Is there a better way to edit? Thanks